# How to control padding inside text labels on connector lines?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io), is there a way to control padding inside text labels on connector lines?

[image: Picture of text label on line connector in Draw.io]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question.

There might be however a workaround depending on what you want to achieve. If you just want it to look nice, you could perhaps remove the background color of the label. That way, you wouldn't see the border and then, maybe, the padding becomes irrelevant.

[image]

Comment: This is a good alternative; thx. Anyways my feeling is I forego the line label (which has the benefit of being attached to the line) and just use manually-placed generic elements.